# How can I keep the <div> inside of the header without messing up the border?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an example page for myself so I'll never forget the basics, but a problem appeared, I set the border of  **<a>** with **border: 5px outset gray;**, but now the **<div id="tab">** appears out of the header, How can I fixed? and if possible, why did that happen?

May you help?

Thanks in advance.

My page on liveweave:http://liveweave.com/yRuhbM;

```css
html{font-family:Courier;}
button{width: 50%;margin: 4%; border-radius: 5px;height: 10.6%;} /*Any button is gonna get those properties, if you don't want it, set it below it*/
label{width: 50%;margin: 4%;}
div{width: 100%;height:20%; color: white; border-radius: 0px;text-align: center;background-color: gray;}
a{text-decoration: none; color: black;border: 5px outset gray;}

.left{float:left;width: 20%;height: 60%;}
.right{float: right;width: 20%; height: 60%;}

#header{margin:auto;top:1px;}
#footer{clear:both;margin:auto;bottom: 10px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5 Page Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="tab">
      
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Home</a>
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="http://www.google.com">About</a>
 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
    <button>Button 4</button>
    <button>Button 5</button>
    <button>Button 6</button>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I was wrong :), It's already fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix, you could add this.

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I eliminated the ul

Comment: @Calne sure, as mentioned in the comments, it's not valid to have <span> or any tags other than <li> directly under <ul>. You could either get rid of the <ul> or keep it then change <span> to <li>. Either way, my suggested solution still works I think.

Answer (score 2):

Add this

```
a{
text-decoration: none; 
display:inline-block; 
color:black;
border: 5px outset gray;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28bozpj1/2/)

Answer (score 2):

First, you should be using `<li>` where you're using `<span>`.

Your anchor elements are pushing outside of your `#header` element for a couple reasons. One is because your `ul` by default has `margin` applied to it by the browser. That top and bottom margin extends out beyond your `#header` element.

The other reason is because `#header` element will only be as tall as it's content or a specified height. Content height can be counter intuitive when working with inline elements like you are doing. The border you are adding to your anchor elements won't count as height because they are inline, switch them to inline block and then the border will.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `<span>` if it is not necessary then remove this else you can use it.and add `<a>` `display:inline-block` in css.
[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/swaranan/k7hh0f4q/)

Comment: I added the spans because I was going to try something different :)

Answer (score 1):

`li` is child of `ul` not `span`, change your markup (you can copy what I've done below) and use the CSS provided below

---

**EDIT**

Also, you should note that setting all the div heights in the entire document should *probably* not be done as every div element in your markup will use these properties. Use classes. It will prevent many headaches you will have. Only style specific html tags if you are sure you always want these properties. That being said you can always override the properties with specificity, but make your life easier and use classes more often. The same thing should be applied to every element in your HTML (even buttons) as you may want to have 2 different buttons if you ever changed your website, or if someone else works on your website eventually

---

```css
html {
    font-family:Courier;
}
button {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 4%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 10.6%;
}
div {
    width: 100%;
    height:20%;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: gray;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: black;
    border: 5px outset gray;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 60%;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    height: 60%;
}
#footer {
    clear:both;
    margin:auto;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="tab">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="left">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
    <button>Button 4</button>
    <button>Button 5</button>
    <button>Button 6</button>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that all browsers style html elements by default.  The body and ul elements in most will by default have margins and padding that you need to override:

```
body, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

However, @paulie-d is correct: you must have an li element as a child of a ul.

To further fix the issues, you'll need to add height to your html and body.

```css
html{font-family:Courier;}
body {margin: 0; padding:0}
ul {margin: 0; padding:0}
button{width: 50%;margin: 4%; border-radius: 5px;height: 10.6%;} /*Any button is gonna get those properties, if you don't want it, set it below it*/
label{width: 50%;margin: 4%;}
div{width: 100%;height:20%; color: white; border-radius: 0px;text-align: center;background-color: gray;}
a{text-decoration: none; color: black;border: 5px outset gray;}

.left{float:left;width: 20%;height: 60%;}
.right{float: right;width: 20%; height: 60%;}

#header{margin:auto;top:1px;}
#footer{clear:both;margin:auto;bottom: 10px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5 Page Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="tab">
      <ul>
        <span><a href="http://www.google.com">Home</a></span>
        <span><a href="http://www.google.com">Contact Us</a></span>
        <span><a href="http://www.google.com">About</a></span>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
    <button>Button 4</button>
    <button>Button 5</button>
    <button>Button 6</button>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, why does my page works on live weave, but when I open it as a file, it looks possessed?

Answer (score 1):

As Pauli_D already pointed out, you need to use `li` inside an `ul` element.
This answer is basically the same as the others in regard of the `a` element but completed with the correct html for the `ul` list.

```css
html{font-family:Courier;}
button{width: 50%;margin: 4%; border-radius: 5px;height: 10.6%;} /*Any button is gonna get those properties, if you don't want it, set it below it*/
label{width: 50%;margin: 4%;}
div{width: 100%;height:20%; color: white; border-radius: 0px;text-align: center;background-color: gray;}
a{text-decoration: none; color: black;border: 5px outset gray;}

.left{float:left;width: 20%;height: 60%;}
.right{float: right;width: 20%; height: 60%;}

#header{margin:auto;top:1px;}
#footer{clear:both;margin:auto;bottom: 10px;}

#tab li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: outside none;
  
}
#tab li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5 Page Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="tab">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
    <button>Button 4</button>
    <button>Button 5</button>
    <button>Button 6</button>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
    <label>blah</label>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```